# unexpected keyword argument 'propagate'

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging module of python. For configuration I am trying to create a config file which is in yaml format. But I am getting error

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file_handler': __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'propagate'
```

whereas I was able to use it `logger.propagate = False`.
I am following [python logging yaml config](https://zetcode.com/python/logging/#:%7E:text=Python%20logging%20YAML%20configuration&text=It%20is%20commonly%20used%20for%20configuration%20files.&text=We%20need%20to%20install%20pyyaml%20module.&text=In%20the%20configuration%20file%2C%20we,case%2C%20to%20the%20root%20logger.) where they have used same config and able to parse it.

This is what my yaml looks like

```
version: 1

formatters:
  simple:
    format: "%(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"

handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple

  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    filename: test_{}.log
    formatter: simple
    propagate: False

loggers:
  dev:
    handlers: [console, file_handler]
  test:
    handlers: [file_handler]
root:
  handlers: [file_handler]
```

This is the error I am getting

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 738, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'propagate'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging_manager.py", line 34, in <module>
    LoggingManager()
  File "logging_manager.py", line 24, in __init__
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 802, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 573, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file_handler': __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'propagate'
```

what am I missing here?

EDIT:
I am using environment

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
```

Comment: ```Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propagate is the property of a logger, not of a handler. You need to remove it from where you have it and put it into the logger section:

```
loggers:
  dev:
    handlers: [console, file_handler]
    propagate: False <---------------------- HERE for example
  test:
    handlers: [file_handler]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me but the link that I shared [python logging yaml config](https://zetcode.com/python/logging/#:~:text=Python%20logging%20YAML%20configuration&text=It%20is%20commonly%20used%20for%20configuration%20files.&text=We%20need%20to%20install%20pyyaml%20module.&text=In%20the%20configuration%20file%2C%20we,case%2C%20to%20the%20root%20logger.) they are doing it at config. How does it work for them any clue?

Comment: It probably doesn't work for them and they didn't double check that the code they paste into their tutorial is the same as what they have on their machine. Propagate on a handler is clearly very wrong, as handlers are not part of a hierarchy, and can be attached to many loggers.